# Рекомендация программы, как программы по умолчанию (Python)

Tags: python, windows, python-3.x

Добрый день! Как сделать так, чтобы при первом запуске моей программы, она рекомендовала себя, как программу по умолчанию. Например, у меня есть созданный мной текстовый редактор, я хочу, чтобы при первом запуске, он предлагал в windows выбрать себя, как программу по умолчанию для файлов .txt
У меня стоит Windows 10.

Comment: Проверять что стоит программой по умолчанию и предлагать вы уже пробовали и вам оно чем-то не подошло? Без этого уточнения вопрос как-то не полон...

Comment: Вопрос заключается в том, что я не знаю как это сделать в Питоне, какие библиотеки использовать

Comment: Почему бы так сразу и не писать: как проверить? А то "как рекомендовать?"

Comment: связанный вопрос [Programatically associate file extensions with application on Windows](https://superuser.com/q/406985/13868)

Answer (score 0):

```
C:\> Assoc .txt
.txt=txtfile


C:\> Ftype txtfile=""
```

Если теперь попробуйте кликнуть .txt, отктоется диалог выбора программы.

Answer (score 0):

```
import os
t = (os.popen('Assoc .txt').read()).strip('\n')
if t[:4] == '.txt' : t = t[5:]
os.system('Ftype ' + t + '=""')
```

Пример использования python для выполнения команд оболочки. `os.system()` и `os.popen()` позволяют выполнять любые команды, понятные оболочке системы